# How Can I get Google Natives apps in Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, google-talk

As you know Samsung Galaxy S comes with yahoo apps (mail, chat, etc). My First Android Phone was a G1 and I really love the google natives apps like gtalk, search widget, etc..  The problem is that these apps are not in the market and I dont know Where to find them.

I know That I could install another Rom that brings theses apps, but I really like How works my samsung with Eclair. I just need back my google apps.

Some help?

Comment: What happens if you try installing from Android Web Market? https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.gm&feature=search_result You need to be logged in to the same Google account as the one you associate with your phone to use Web Market.

Comment: I had no idea the SGS came with Yahoo instead of Google apps in Nicaragua.  That's crazy.

Comment: @Lie Ryan I already did that but in market.android.com when I want to install tell me that this item is not aviable for my operator. Probably because detects the country of my google account u_u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you searched in the market using ["Google" as the publisher](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Google+Inc.)?

Gmail / Maps / Search are available there.

Also found this link - http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/Instant-Messenger/GTalk-106808.shtml

Comment: Probably I have restriction for my country in the market, If I search "Google" I just see Google Translate, google reader, google goggles, But Still missing, gtalk, gmail, and search widget

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: Nicaragua. Yep thanks for the link gtalk apk Works :)

Answer (score 2):

Installing from Market is preferrable, but you probably can sideload them if you exhausted all other avenues.

Download the apk: http://forum.samdroid.net/f10/google-updates-3468/

If you have adb, then you can install the apk using adb install.

If you don't have adb, then save those apks to the SD card and use a file manager (e.g. Astro, Estrongs, etc) to install them.

You need to enable non-Market installation: Settings > Applications > Unknown sources